# Python3 Binary Stream Processing - Read Single JPG Off Stdin

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, ipc

We have a system composed of multiple processes, connected by IPC over stdin/stdout. Previously we were relying on line delimiters and non-binary input to perform this IPC, base64-encoding binary data before transport. Due to resource constraints, we're removing base64 encoding from this IPC and switching to raw binary-based IPC over `sys.stdin.buffer`.

The python process in question loops infinitely over inputs composed of multiple data fields, most of which are fixed length and easy to parse based on this length. JPG data has well-defined head/foot bytes which can be used to determine when you've reached the end of the image, but the naive approach to reading this data byte-by-byte has negative performance impacts and manual buffer management associated with reading in larger chunks and needing to handle "over-reading" is not appealing.

I'm a relative novice to Python development and am curious whether I'm missing a better approach than the two options mentioned above 1) read byte-by-byte and 2) read in larger (more performant) chunks and manually implent buffer management where read consumes bytes past the end of the JPG being read.

Comment: maybe first send data size - ie. `10;HelloWorld` - and then you will know how much data you have to read.

Comment: @furas Thanks -- yes, that's actually a great idea.

Comment: this method is sometimes used when people send by `socket` without using protocols like `HTTP`, `FTP`, etc. In current version you have size as string which may have different length and you have to read byte-by-byte until you get `;` but you can use constant length for all sizes - ie. 10 chars `000000010;HelloWorld` and then you can always first read 10 chars to get size - it is faster and easier. if you need bigger values then you can also use module [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) to convert integer to 4-bytes (`pack()`) and conver 4-bytes to integer (`unpack()`)